# AVD can't run applications

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Im a newbie experiencing issues with the emulator..basically whenever i try to run my program in eclipse with a new AVD created.the app crashes/hangs and says "unfortunately app has stopped"...ive tried all usual tricks of cleaning and restarting as many of the threads here have mentioned, but to no success.

below is a link to my logcat
http://i59.tinypic.com/3342edd.png

this is a link to my Console
http://i62.tinypic.com/vy1mj4.png

This is my logcat here also

```
02-22 22:51:52.460: D/AndroidRuntime(821): Shutting down VM
02-22 22:51:52.460: W/dalvikvm(821): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a6db90)
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821): Process: com.simplytapp.example.singlecard, PID: 821
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.cardemu cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.cardemu cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.cardemu cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.cardemu cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.cardemu cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.oauth cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.virtualcard cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.virtualcard cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The import com.simplytapp.virtualcard cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardEmu cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Constants cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Constants cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Syntax error on token "U7Ls53wGtTCkQ5iHdRCJiHemTA1FP5wyi91Xc", delete this token
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Constants cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Syntax error on token "cfmOo4Lem8pZWAYRhKBtKmSNwk9MuyzYtOT6X", delete this token
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Constants cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  st_oauth_callback_YOUR_APP_NAME cannot be resolved to a variable
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Constants cannot be resolved
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  x cannot be resolved to a variable
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  oauthflow cannot be resolved to a variable
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardDetails cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardEmu cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardEmu cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardEmu cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method onCreate(Bundle) of type SingleCardActivity must override or implement a supertype method
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardEmu cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type SingleCardActivity
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type SingleCardActivity
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardDetails cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method getIntent() is undefined for the type SingleCardActivity
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method getIntent() is undefined for the type SingleCardActivity
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method loadCards() is undefined for the type SingleCardActivity
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method getCardError(IOException, String) of type SingleCardActivity must override or implement a supertype method
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardEmu cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  VirtualCard cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  ApprovalData cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method cardsLoaded(ArrayList<CardDetails>, boolean) of type SingleCardActivity must override or implement a supertype method
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardDetails cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  List<CardDetails> cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardDetails cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(SingleCardActivity) is undefined
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Card cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Message cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method getHandler() is undefined for the type SingleCardActivity
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method cardsRemoved() of type SingleCardActivity must override or implement a supertype method
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type SingleCardActivity
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Pin cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method setPin(String) in the type SingleCardActivity is not applicable for the arguments (Pin)
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Pin cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(SingleCardActivity) is undefined
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method from(Context) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (SingleCardActivity)
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method setUsePin(boolean) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method setPin(String) in the type SingleCardActivity is not applicable for the arguments (Pin)
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  Pin cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  PinInterface cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method getPinInterfaceSetting() of type SingleCardActivity must override or implement a supertype method
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  PinInterface cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  ManagePin cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  ManagePin cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type SingleCardActivity must override or implement a supertype method
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type SingleCardActivity
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type SingleCardActivity must override or implement a supertype method
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  CardEmu cannot be resolved to a type
02-22 22:51:52.470: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  The method onStart() of type SingleCardActivity must o
02-22 22:56:52.995: I/Process(821): Sending signal. PID: 821 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the logcat here. (p.s. What you have linked as the "logcat" is actually the console.

Comment: can you post the code...

Answer (score 0):

i think you are new in android. try to read error log. oncreate must be like this.

```
public class SingleActivityCard extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Hello World, Android - mkyong.com");
        setContentView(text);
    }
}
```

Check oncreate method of SingleCardActivity and make sure first line of these method must be `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

and another one also specify @override above your oncreate method

2 )in console you also facing problem **error accepting Connection** so you should resetadb from DDMS and restart your eclipse if you again facing same problem then just re create new AVD

Comment: hey thanks for the reply...my on create method is intact the way you said it should be..i have created a new AVD too..still no succsss